# How to use Pyautogui on a Windows EC2 instance without RDP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pyautogui

Is it possible to operate a Windows Server (or desktop variant) EC2 instance as though I was sitting directly in front of the monitor and keyboard?

The reason I'm asking is because I have an automation service that is built in Python and Pyautogui that controls the mouse and keyboard and performs certain actions on the browser and the file system. The service doesn't function if I start an RDP session and then disconnect from it. I also can't keep an RDP session open all the time.

I want to be able to migrate this service to an EC2 instance but can't figure out how to operate it this way (sort of like an admin console mode perhaps)?

Is this possible and how can it be done?